# What is the current role of the suggested edit review queue on the meta sites?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits, per-site-meta

On the meta sites (including discuss.area51), <2k users can't suggest edits to posts.

The edits of the 2k+ users happen without any review, as on the main sites.

This results in the edit review queue being empty, and it will remain empty until eternity.

Could it be removed, or are there some rare cases when there is something for review?

Comment: I think tag edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggested edits for tag wikis can still be made (by anyone, except anonymous users) and reviewed by users with the privilege (5k on graduated sites). [Example](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/69).

Unfortunately, there's no easy way at present to [only show the queue to those with that privilege](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256417/users-with-5k-rep-should-not-see-the-suggested-edit-queue-enabled-on-per-site); it's available (but permanently empty) to everyone between 2k and 5k.